# [Vite - Vue 3]Page not found when reload page on Github

Tags: github, vue-router, vuejs3, vite

When I click router-link to redirect to another page, it loads successfully.

But after reloading, the page is not found.

I use Vite 2.6, Vue 3.2 and Vue Router 4.0.

In local, it still works fine, it only fail on my github.io.

vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
    base: 'study',
    plugins: [vue()],
    build: {
        sourcemap: false,
    },
});
```

routes.js

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router';
import Home from './views/Home.vue';
const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'Home',
        component: Home,
    }
];
export default function () {
    return createRouter({
        history: createWebHistory('/study'),
        routes,
    });
}
```

main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import createRouter from './router/routes';

const router = createRouter();
const app = createApp(App);
app.use(router);
app.mount('#app');
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you share the code of the `index.html` please ?

Answer (score 1):

You better use apache or nginx for hosting your files
In /dist folder create a file and called It .htaccess then put those lines in It. as mention [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#apache)

**For Apache**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Then copy all files from dist to hdocs in apache main folder